# View object in oracle adf

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-adf

I work with one application module which uses view object to manage database table. The problem occurs while this process:

1. I insert new record into the table using java implementation of view object
2. I find and update this new record using java implementation of view object
3. I delete this record from table (any way to delete)
4. I repeat step 1
5. I repeat step 2 AND THE EXCEPTION SAYS THAT THERE ARE NO THIS RECORD IN THE TABLE

Steps 1-5 are processed in deployed application. Funny thing is that after I redeploy the application and go to the step 5 it works!
It seems that view object isn't updated properly, but I don't know where to make changes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, only one line of code solves the problem :) After I finish using AppModule I invoke

```
Configuration.releaseRootApplicationModule(appModule, true);
```